# multiple images on web page using asp.net

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net

I am fetching images from database and going to display images on web page,i want to display show more images button if images are more and also want to display  that more images on same web page automatically if user click on show more button in ASP.Net

Comment: show your code please.

Comment: rather than expecting everything from others, atleast show some efforts that what you _tried_

Answer (score 1):

You can use a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptStudentDetails" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table border="1" cellpadding="1">
            <tr style="background-color: #fa7b16; color: #FFF; height: 35px;" align="center">
                <th>
                    Student Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Class
                </th>
                <th>
                    Age
                </th>
                <th>
                    Gender
                </th>
                <th>
                    Address
                </th>
            </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr style="background-color: white;" align="center">
            <td>
                <%#Eval("StudentName") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Class") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Age") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Gender") %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%#Eval("Address") %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
<asp:Button ID="btnLoadMore" runat="server" Text="Load More Data" OnClick="btnLoadMore_Click" />
```

In your code-behind .cs file

```
protected void btnLoadMore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //On every click of this button it will add 2 to the ViewState["num"] whose value was set to 2 initially on page load. So numval is 4 now.
    int numVal = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["num"]) + 2;
    //Now pass numVal whose value is 4 to the BindRepeater function to get 4 rows.
    BindRepeater(numVal);
    //Set ViewState["num"] is equal to the numVal i.e. 4 so that when we again click this button it will be 4 + 2= 6 and so on.
    ViewState["num"] = numVal;
}
private void BindRepeater(int numOfRows)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = null;
    SqlDataAdapter adp = null;
    try
    {
        //get number rows in table by calling the rowCount function i created.
        int rCount = rowCount();
        // hide the "Load More Data button" if the number of request rows becomes greater than the rows in table
        if (numOfRows > rCount)
        {
            btnLoadMore.Visible = false;
        }
        cmd = new SqlCommand("GetStudentDetails_SP", con);
        //Passs numOfRows variable value to stored procedure to get desired number of rows
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@topVal", numOfRows);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            rptStudentDetails.DataSource = dt;
            rptStudentDetails.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

**Refer to the Url's below for more details:**

[Asp.Net Load more data records on button click in Repeater Control from sql server table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gAFLxz96RHE)

[LOAD MORE DATA RECORDS ON BUTTON CLICK IN ASP.NET REPEATER FROM SQL SERVER TABLE](http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2014/05/load-more-data-records-on-button-click.html)